# Can I paint over this?

Tags: paint, preparation

Can I paint over

**Dulux Kitchens and bathrooms moisture resistant soft sheen emulusion**

with

**Dulux kitchen+ grease and stain protection Matt** ?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there'd be any problems. After all, when the moisture resistant paint was first put on, more than one coat would have been used, therefore it is possible to paint over it. Just make sure you give the wall a good clean (i.e. use sugar soap) before putting the new paint on.